# Copy and Paste contents from another workbook into current workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code that downloads an excel file from the web. I need it to copy and paste its contents into my current workbook, but I get the "Subscript out of range" error. Code is below, and thanks in advance!

```
Sub dwnld()
  Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
  IE.Visible = True
  IE.navigate "http://broomfield.flatironslibrary.org/"

  While IE.Busy
    DoEvents
  Wend
  Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
  Loop

 IE.document.getElementsByClassName("hidden-xs header-button header-primary")(0).Click
 Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:02 AM#)
 IE.document.getElementById("username").Value = "user"
 IE.document.getElementById("password").Value = "pass"
 IE.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary extraModalButton")(0).Click
 Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:02 AM#)
 IE.navigate ("http://broomfield.flatironslibrary.org/MyAccount/CheckedOut?exportToExcel")
 Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:02 AM#)
 Application.SendKeys ("%o")
 Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:05 AM#)
 Call CopyingRange

End Sub
```

Copying Range Code:

```
Sub CopyingRange()
  Workbooks("CheckedOutItems").Sheets("Checked Out").Range("A3:E62").Copy Range("B2")
End Sub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some indention to your code.

Comment: IDK what you mean. On my screen, the code is indented.

Comment: It's indented for me too. When you hit "debug" on the error, where is it highlighting?

Comment: check if a workbook named "CheckedOutItems" with a sheet named "Checked Out" is actually open when you run the macro

Comment: The debugger is highlighting the code that you provided, like before

Comment: @Mark did you do that check about open workbook and sheet name?  you could type in Immediate Window `? Workbooks("CheckedOutItems").Sheets("Checked Out").Range("A3:E62").Address` and press enter. Should it throw an error then the culprit would be that left part of the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code below for CopyingRange

```
Sub CopyingRange()
      Workbooks("CheckedOutItems").Sheets("Checked Out").Range("A3:E62").Copy ThisWorkBook.ActiveSheet.Range("B2")
End Sub
```

Good luck!

Comment: Still not working. The debugger is highlighting the code that you provided, like before.